# Accessing google apps email on outlook 2010?

Tags: imap, microsoft-outlook-2010

I am a college student, and I use outlook 2010 for my primary email, however, my school uses a gmail account for our college email.  This account isn't even truly gmail, it's a google application for email and so I am having trouble adding my college email to outlook.  Does anyone know what the incoming mail server would be for this? I'm truly stumped...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this question:
[How do I sync Gmail with Outlook 2010?](https://superuser.com/questions/169467/how-to-sync-gmail-with-outlook-2010/169504#169504)

Unfortunately, there as some issues with Outlook 2010 and the Google Apps Sync tool. Hopefully they get that resolved soon (I'm also a Google Apps for EDU and Outlook 2010 user), but in the meantime you'll have to use the imap solution.  Instructions for imap with Gmail can be found here:

http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=77689

Those instructions are for Outlook 2007, but this at least is still pretty much the same for Outlook 2010.

To summarize the key points:

- First, don't forget to [enable imap in gmail](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=77695)
- Your incoming mail server is `imap.gmail.com` on port 993 with SSL encryption
- Your outgoing mail server is `smtp.gmail.com` on port 587 with TLS encryption
- Your username is your full e-mail address. This is especially important for Google Apps for my domain users such as yourself.
- The smtp server uses the same authentication as the incoming server

Note that when you first tell it to use encryption on a server, it will set the default port for you.  So if you enter the port first, make sure it didn't over-write your port selection.

**Update**
The Google Apps Sync tool now support Outlook 2010.  If you have Google Apps Premier or Google Apps for Education, you can get it here:
https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gappssync

Comment: The thing that I think makes this not work is the fact that my email is not ...@gmail.com it's ...@<school_name>.edu I believe that this causes issues with domains and servers...

Comment: I'm giving up, I simply put my Outlook email as the forwarding address. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @Glen - This works fine with @school.edu addresses.  I use it myself.

Comment: I've never seen a university that doesn't have its own mailservers.

Comment: @jason - Then let me introduce to your first.  I'm Director of IT at a school that outsources e-mail to Google. Our only smtp server is a little thing we use to handle mail generated by a few temperature sensors around campus.  Between Google Apps for My Domain EDU edition and Microsoft Live Mail EDU edition (both of which are _free_) there are quite a few colleges and universities that now choose this option, with more all the time.

Comment: @Joel: Interesting.  However, I cannot see that happening here in UK universities, any time soon.

Comment: @Glenn I updated my answer. If you're still having trouble with this check out the link at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

See [How to Configure Outlook 2010 For Gmail and Google Apps Accounts](http://www.ampercent.com/configure-outlook2010-gmail-gogole-apps/6193/).

Comment: this didn't work, i found something just like it before but it never seemed to work for me

Comment: I'm giving up, I simply put my Outlook email as the forwarding address. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use Outlook 2010 with Google Apps:
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Apps/thread?tid=5d8ef1be80f771fd&hl=en

Google Apps Sync versions 2.0.499.2346 (for 32-bit Outlook) and 2.0.500.23 (for 64-bit Outlook) are now available for all new downloads. Existing installs will be updated gradually over the next few weeks.
What’s New:
Support for Microsoft Outlook® 2010
Rich contact data available in the Global Address List
Enhanced support for custom From addresses

Answer (score 0):

I am using Google sync between outlook 2010 64 bit and google apps premier addition without any problem. It's a life saver for me!

Answer (score 0):

We have had nothing but problems with our Google Apps e-mail migrations to Outlook 2010.  Here is a short list of the most serious problems:  (1) Can't have an exchange server e-mail connection alongside Google Apps e-mail and have Google Apps still send e-mail in Outlook 2010.  (2) Some users with just a Google Apps e-mail address in their profile appear to send e-mail which "vanishes" mysteriously - no Sent Items, no Drafts, no Outbox - just "poof"!  (3) strange "from" in e-mails to groups.  (4) Problems with sharing of calendar information.  (5) events/meetings that appear in calendars without any "invite".  (6) Problems with sync failing or hanging up Outlook.

We have contractors working for us that use Outlook 2010 to connect with their client e-mail accounts and keep calendars organized - we have lost this ability.   Some users have gone two days without e-mails being delivered before they noticed and no errors AT ALL were reported.

All I can say is that Outlook 2010 integration is still seriously BETA and has numerous critical issues that are not yet resolved.  I would not recommend a migration at this time if anyone is considering it.